# A solution for $\int^{2\pi}_0e^{\cos \theta}\cos(a\theta -\sin \theta)\,d \theta $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

It can be proved using complex analysis that

$$\tag{1}\int^{2\pi}_0e^{\cos \theta}\cos(n\theta -\sin \theta)=\frac{2\pi}{n!}$$

My initial thought that,  we use the Gamma function for non-integer values. But it seems that we cannot since

$$\int^{2\pi}_0e^{\cos \theta}\cos\left(\left(\frac{1}{2} +n\right)\theta -\sin \theta \right)=0$$

My Question : Can we solve

$$\int^{2\pi}_0e^{\cos \theta}\cos(a\theta -\sin \theta)\,d \theta $$

for specific values of $a$ that are not of the above cases ?

**EDIT**

As requested in the comments here is a proof of (1) using contour integeration

Consider the following function

$$f(z)=e^{z^{-1}}z^{n-1}$$

Now we integrate the function along a circle of radius 1

$$\oint_{|z|=1}e^{z^{-1}}z^{n-1} dz=\oint_{|z|=1}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{z^{n-k-1}}{\, k!} dz  $$

Now we need to find the residue which is the coefficient of $1/z$

$$\text{Assume that } n-k-1=-1 \to n=k$$

Hence we have

$$\oint_{|z|=1}e^{z^{-1}}z^{n-1} dz= 2\pi i \frac{1}{n!}  $$

Using a parametirzation of the circle

$$i\int_{0}^{2\pi i}e^{e^{-i\theta }}e^{i n\theta } d\theta = 2\pi i \frac{1}{n!}  $$

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi i}e^{e^{-i\theta }}e^{i n\theta } d\theta = 2\pi\frac{1}{n!}  $$

Hence we have

$$\Re\int_{0}^{2\pi i}e^{e^{-i\theta }}e^{i n\theta } d\theta =\int^{2\pi i}_0 e^{\cos \theta} \cos(n\theta-\sin \theta)\, d\theta= \frac{2\pi}{n!}  $$

Comment: could you be more clearer by specific values of $a$??

Comment: @SantoshLinkha: He means for any other general value of $a$, or at least some values that aren't of the above form.

Comment: @mixedmath could it be complex variable? or just real?

Comment: @SantoshLinkha, yes any value.

Comment: Very close [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595800/evaluate-the-bessel-function-j-int2-pi-0e-cos-x-cos2x-sin-x?rq=1), where the case $n=2$ is considered.

Comment: @user64494, yes. In the title the OP is calling the integral  a bessel function. I don't know how ?

Comment: Do you have a link for the proof by complex analysis?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar, I edited my question. It has the solution using complex analysis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can obtain the solution for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ in terms of the incomplete Gamma function:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int _{0}^{2\,\pi }\!{{\rm e}^{\cos \left( \theta \right) }}\cos
 \left( n\theta-\sin \left( \theta \right)  \right) {d\theta}&={\it Re}
 \left( \int _{0}^{2\,\pi }\!{{\rm e}^{{{\rm e}^{-i\theta}}}}{{\rm e}^
{in\theta}}{d\theta} \right) \\
&={\it Re}
 \left( \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \left( {\frac {\int _{0}^{2\,\pi }\!{
{\rm e}^{-i\theta\,k}}{{\rm e}^{ia\theta}}{d\theta}}{k!}} \right) 
 \right) \\
&=-\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\,{\frac {\sin \left( 2\,\pi \,a \right) }{
 \left( k-a \right) k!}}
 \\
&= \left( -1 \right) ^{a}\sin \left( 2\,\pi \,a \right) 
 \left[\Gamma  \left( -a,-1 \right)- \Gamma  \left( -a\right) \right]
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\Gamma(-a, -1)$ is the [incomplete Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)

Comment: How about complex values of $a$?

Comment: @user64494: $\Gamma(z,x)$ is defined for complex values of $z$.